# Getting or Setting the length of an hexadecimal String in Php

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert three types of ints (8,16 & 32 bits), to fixed lengths hexadecimal Strings, in Php.

As an example, the third int is 32 bits unsigned. 
Its value is set to 300. Converting it to hexadecimal, gives me 12c.

I want to always get a fixed six characters hexadecimal String from my int, i.e in this example : 00 01 2c ... or 00 00 78 if my int's value is 120.
(N.B : I know 32 bits would overcome this range)

Is there any way of getting the length of an hexadecimal String in Php ?
Another strategy would be to define the length of the hexa String, but I did not find anything regarding this.

My goal is just to be able to always send a 6 chars sized hexadecimal String to a connected object.

I used 'dechex()' to convert my values to hexadecimal, but I never know the numbers of characters of the output, and therefore can't add a particular number of zeros to it (for my final hex String to be 6 chars long).

I've read something about setting PHP_INT_MAX, but I also read that it would affect all ints, which I don't want.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php)

```
<?php
$number = 4;
$hexString = dechex($number);
$result = str_pad($hexString,6,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo($result);
?>
```

Comment: it's linking the official documentation now

Comment: Thanks namelivia, this is exactly what I needed. Seeing the simplicity of your answer I feel much like a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

Use [printf()](http://php.net/printf)

```
printf('%06x', 32); // 0000206
//       ^----zero-pad
//        ^---6 char string
//         ^--hex output
```

Comment: Thanks Marc B, I had tried this, but for some reason it didn't output my String as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$number = 300;
$hex_string = chunk_split(sprintf('%06x', $number), 2, ' ');
echo $hex_string;

?>
```